# C# Add Object To List

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, list

I have created a new empty List of type **User** (**User** is an Entity in my EDM)

```
List<User> AvailableLocums = new List<User>();
AvailableLocums = null;
```

I also have another List of type **User** which is populated with the results of a query

```
List<User> Locums = _shiftDateService.GetAvailableLocums(id, shiftDate.shiftDateID).ToList();
```

I then wish to loop around the **Locums** List, do some logic, and then add the User to my **AvailableLocums** List

```
foreach (var locum in Locums)
{
   //Do some logic

   AvailableLocums.Add(locum);

}
```

However, when I try to do this I get the following error

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I then tried to amend my code and do the following

```
foreach (var locum in Locums)
{
       //Do some logic

       User locumUser = new User();
       locumUser = locum;

       AvailableLocums.Add(locumUser);     
}
```

But again I get the same error

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Could someone please help me with this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are nulling out that list

```
List<User> AvailableLocums = new List<User>();
AvailableLocums = null; // HERE
```

hence, the exception. You don't need this line to make an empty list:

```
AvailableLocums = null;
```

Answer (score 5):

You are telling your variable "AvailableLocums" to no longer point to anything in memory.

Remove:
AvailableLocums = null;

how about:

```
List<User> AvailableLocums;
List<User> Locums;

// get id for shift date service
// int id = ...

// get locums from shift date service 
Locums = _shiftDateService.GetAvailableLocums(id, shiftDate.shiftDateID).ToList();

// time to add to AvailableLocums
if(AvailableLocums == null)
    AvailableLocums = new List<User>();

foreach (var locum in Locums)
{
   //Do some logic

   AvailableLocums.Add(locum);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

get out this line :

```
AvailableLocums = null;
```

and it will be Ok ...
You declaring new object and on next row set it to null?

Answer (score 0):

try to

```
List<User> Locums = new List<User>();
```

before _shiftDateService.GetAvailableLocums...

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
List<User> AvailableLocums = null; 
List<User> Locums = _shiftDateService.GetAvailableLocums(id, shiftDate.shiftDateID).ToList();  
AvailableLocums = Locums.Where(newUserRecord => newUserRecord != null).ToList();
```

*** you can take any name instead of "newUserRecord".

Comment: you can use Lambda expression instead of using foreach